# Aborting a query using trpc react-query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, tanstackreact-query, trpc

## Reference

### Canceling with React Query

The standard way to abort a query using react-query is to use the AbortController to abort the fetch request (reference https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-cancellation):

```
const query = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['todos'],
  queryFn: async ({ signal }) => {
    const resp = await fetch('/todos', { signal })
    return resp.json()
  },
})

const queryClient = useQueryClient()

return (
  <button
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ['todos'] })
    }}
  >
    Cancel
  </button>
)
```

### Cancelling with TRPC Proxy Client

You can use an abort controller with this as well (reference https://trpc.io/docs/client/vanilla/aborting-procedure-calls):

```
// 1. Create an AbortController instance - this is a standard javascript API
const ac = new AbortController();
 
// 2. Pass the signal to a query or mutation
const query = proxy.userById.query('id_bilbo', { signal: ac.signal });
 
// 3. Cancel the request if needed
ac.abort();
```

## Question

### Cancelling with TRPC React Query Client

This is where I am lost. Here we do not have the access to the underlying `fetch` (which we did in standard React Query) and there is no way to pass in a signal that I could find in the docs. You can see the docs here : https://trpc.io/docs/client/react/aborting-procedure-calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work by passing `abortOnUnmount: true` (as shown in the docs link you posted). Contrary to the name, this just forwards the `AbortSignal` to `fetch`, which means requests will also be cancelled if you call `trpc.useUtils().userById.cancel()`

Comment: That should do it. Thanks 